# KVO notifications with textView.text

Tags: ios, uitextview, key-value-observing

I need notifications with textView.text, but the do not work.

My code:

Add a KVO:

```
[textView addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"text"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:nil];
```

Observing method

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                 ofObject:(id)object
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change
                  context:(void *)context
```

I am trying change contentSize. KVO is working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html

> Note: Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO, you can still implement it in the custom objects of your application, including custom views.

There have another way to help you simply.

- Conform `UITextViewDelegate` protocol methods.
- Use method `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;` to get `textView.text` changed.

Comment: i notifications `textView.text`,because textView call `setText` sometime. thanks. kvo not work,because `textView.text` is not  object?